# My React native app keeps Throwing UUID error even when i dont have it in my code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, uuid

I tried using UUID in my react native application, but since it did not work i decided to clear the code.. But ever since then, when i try running my Code again, i keep getting this error

```
Unable to resolve module uuid from C:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Desktop\port\app\node_modules\expo\build\logs\RemoteLogging.js: uuid could not be found within the project or in these directories:
```

node_modules
........\node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
   3 | import { EventEmitter } from 'fbemitter';
   4 | import invariant from 'invariant';

> 5 | import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
> |                               ^
> 6 | import getInstallationIdAsync from '../environment/getInstallationIdAsync';
> 7 | import LogSerialization from './LogSerialization';
> 8 | const _sessionId = uuidv4();

Comment: You have a dependency which is trying to use the `uuid` package, but it isn't installed. Try installing `uuid` as a dependency using `npm`/`yarn`/whatever package manager you use

Comment: react uses the uuid package so delete the node modules folder and run npm install